# Cost allocation to List of items

Tags: algorithm, math

I have some dollar value .I have to allocate it to list of items based on dimensional weight.I have to maintain the precision to two digit.

One option is to keep allocating iteratively until those extra penny is not allocated.

For example I have three items a, b and c .All have weight as 3lb and I want to allocate $10 to these items .I'll have to do one more iteration to allocate extra penny to complete the allocation.

Another Example is

```
Amount = $100.06
total number of items =10
weight of each items =1 lb
```

How should I allocate 6 cents in this case?
Is there any better way to allocate the cost to all items?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please add a [mcve] detailing your code. Explain why it does not work and post the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

No one can tell you a better way until you say what you are trying to optimize.  But this appears to be a bin-packing program, and they are generally NP-complete.  Read the Wikipedia entry on bin packing.